Resistor and Capacitor before Op-amp Follower Circuit
I am still working on a personal project to use an Electrosmith Daisy Seed as a guitar pedal. While doing some research, I came up with my own textbook inverting amplifier setup to take the 10kOhm impedance output with 10dBV (9V p2p) of another guitar pedal and shrink it to values that the Daisy Seed ADC can handle ie. 3.6V p2p while providing high input impedance (1MOhm as seems to be standard).
While looking some more I found this website which offers guitar pedal PCBs and one specifically for the Daisy Seed. The documentation for this shows the solution for feeding audio into the Daisy Seed, and I am rather puzzled by the circuit:

I understand that the op-amp is setup as a voltage follower, I also understand that the voltage divider R1&R3 will bias the signal for the op-amp, and I will take a guess and say that C6 serves as DC blocker. But then I am puzzled by the functions of C1 and R7, as well as C7.

Why are they here ? Especially R7, I thought I could just bias the signal using the voltage divider and go straight into the op-amp, why is R7 there ?

Secondly, I am also unsure about what guarantees that the incoming signal won't fry the Daisy Seed, as the voltage follower does not scale it down to +1.8V/-1.8V and no DC blocking capacitor is on the output side to un-bias the signal. Am I missing something ? I guess the TL072 VCC is 5V from the L78L05 voltage regulator, could that be what limits the signal and avoids frying the Daisy Seed, but wouldn't that damage the TL072 ?


Thank you for helping me understand, as this ready-made solution differs greatly from the solution I came up with on my own and with the help of the nice people in the previous thread I posted.

C1 acts as a filter against high frequency interference, for example cellphone signals. Without it any RF picked up by the cables can be rectified by the opamp's input stage and produce audible interference. C1 should have as low as possible impedance at high frequency, which means low inductance, so a good choice would be a SMD ceramic capacitor. It should be located as close as possible to the input connector. If the connector is shielded and the shield connected to the chassis at the connector, then C1 will short the incoming RF to the chassis and not inject it into the circuit's ground, which could cause problems.
R7 and C7 are another layer of lowpass filter for the same purpose. R7 adds impedance to the source, making C7 more effective. The cutoff frequency of this filter is way above the audio band, so it does not produce any audible effect besides preventing interference from getting into the signal.
R7 also limits excessive current that may flow into the TL072 inputs in case the input voltage rises above the supply or below ground. The value is a bit low for this, maybe 10k would be preferable.
R1 uses 5V as bias source, so this voltage should be clean. It should not be unfiltered +5V from a USB power bank using a switching converter for example.
According to the documentation you linked, the opamp in the schematic is a TL072 powered by a single +5V/0V supply. Its output can't go outside of its supply range. The Daisy Seed uses a 5V audio codec, whose inputs can tolerate 0 to 5V, so the ADC should be fine. Besides, this is not a rail to rail opamp, so its output voltage can only reach about 1.5-2V away from the supplies. Its input stage also has a common mode restriction on the negative side.
This will limit the p2p output voltage also. So the opamp should clip at a rather low voltage like +/-1V or maybe less. If it hits the input stage common mode voltage limit before the output stage clips, then it will clip asymmetrically. So if the gear you use before that has max 9Vpp output you will need to turn down its volume knob.

Wow, thank you for this very complete answer. My knowledge of electronics is limited and so, I'm afraid I could not understand thoroughly everything you explained, although I get an idea as I know what an RC filter is. The part about R7 limiting current flow especially surprised me, although I understand the argument, I thought op-map circuits would mention this safety mechanism, I'm surprised I never saw it before. All in all this circuit's clipping behavior seems rather constraining for my intended 10dBV incoming signal use. Should I combine a 12V/0V 0.4 gain op-amp with a 5V/0V follower ?

Oh, and what about DC blocking on the output side ? After biasing the input signal with the voltage divider I don't see anything to undo it before going into the Daisy Seed ?

Daisy docs say analog inputs are AC coupled so the caps are probably already on the Daisy. For R7, TL072 datasheet from TI says "Input pins are diode-clamped to the power-supply rails. Input signals that can swing more than 0.5 V beyond the supply rails must be current limited to 10 mA or less." so the 1k resistor would be alright for going a few volts above the supply, limiting to a few mA, no issue. Only +15V input signal would reach the max current of 10mA.

If the previous pedal doesn't have a volume knob, you could use a resistive divider, or a 12V opamp as buffer followed by a resistive attenuator. Most opamps will be unstable with gain below 1 in non inverting configuration, so it's best to use a follower then a resistive divider.

Okay, thank you very much for all this information ! Currently my schematics feature an inverting 0.4 gain 12V/0V Texas Instruments LM258DR op amp.  Would inverting be OK ?  Otherwise I'll stick with your solution of non inverting and voltage divider (made of resistors).

Yes, an inverting opamp will be stable with gain lower than 1. Its input impedance is equal to the first resistor. LM258 isn't well suited for audio, it has quite high noise and lots of distortion. Since you'll use quite high resistors it's better to pick an opamp with low input current noise as this gets multiplied by the feedback resistors, so a FET input opamp. You could use TL072, or its upgraded version TL072H which will work better on 5V, or for lower noise OPA1678 or OPA1652

Thank you very much for all this help ! I'll go back to the drawing board and change my schematics to implement a OPA1678 or OPA1652 12V/0V 0.4 gain inverting op amp solution, and put the offset/bias on the +input of the opamp. I'll try to add the C1 now that you mentioned it's used to remove HF noise. Is it ok if I post the result in a new thread ? I wouldn't want to spam the electronics stackexchange, but since I'm sailing blind, every bit of confirmation I can get helps greatly. Thank you again.

If the opamp is inverting with gain<1 and bias on the + input, then the - input will be at the same voltage as the + input, and the output will be 0-5V. So it doesn't need 12V supply, it'll work fine with 0-5V supply. It's a perk of the inverting circuit, the input voltage is on the other side of the input resistor, so the input voltage can be above the opamp's supply and it will work as long as the opamp doesnt clip too much. Also it is better to use 0-5V because it limits the output to safe voltages for your ADC. Yes you can ask more questions, that's what this website is for, no problem!

Ok ! I've tried to apply your advice and posted a thread for verification: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/721665/inverting-amplifier-for-impedance-and-scaling-before-electrosmith-daisy-seed
